# unittest assertRaise still raise exception

Tags: python

here is my code, I write a decorater which will raise a RuntimeError, in the testcase, I use assertRaises to make sure the exception have raised. but When I run the program, the program still interrupt by exception. I think it should show me that the test case pass!

```
import unittest
import decorators

def not_completed(func):
  """
  Prevent user from calling not fully implemented functions.
  """
  raise RuntimeError("This function is not fully implemented: {}".format(func.__name__))


@not_completed
def test_not_completed(a, b):
  print("invoke test", a+b)


class TestDecorators(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_not_completed(self):
    with self.assertRaises(RuntimeError):
      decorators.test_not_completed(1, 3)
```

This is the result output:

> ```
>  File "E:\nutstore\Temp\hhw_dev_tools\decorators.py", line 8, in <module>
>     @not_completed
>   File "E:\nutstore\Temp\hhw_dev_tools\decorators.py", line 5, in not_completed
>     raise RuntimeError("This function is not fully implemented: {}".format(func.__name__))
> RuntimeError: This function is not fully implemented: test_not_completed
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `not_completed` running in import time

```
@not_completed
def test_not_completed(a, b):
  print("invoke test", a+b)
```

is

```
def test_not_completed(a, b):
  print("invoke test", a+b)
test_not_completed = not_completed(test_not_completed)
```

So not_completed is not running inside the resource manager

Comment: thanks, I think I need find out other way of writing test case for this scenario.